# lwjgl, how do I make a shape follow the mouse? Not as easy as I thought

Tags: java, mouse, lwjgl

I'm using a combination of slick2d and lwjgl, and i'm trying to make my main menu using collision with a rectangle thats placed around a button, and a circle that follows my mouse. Problem is, the circle doesn't follow the right x or y coords even though I have them set as Mouse.getX() and Mouse.getY(), its kinda like inversed. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If its inverted, then

```
int circley = -Mouse.getY();
int circlex = -Mouse.getX();
```

although, i would do something like:

```
int circley += Mouse.getDY();
```

even better would be to call a

```
 circle.update(Mouse.getDX(), Mouse.getDY())
```

in your game loop, and a function in your circle class of update(int DX, int DY)

```
public void update(int DX, int DY){
    this.x += DX;
    this.y += DY;
}
```